# Fast file writing in C++

Tags: c++

I'm working in a system that use PHYSFS to search files. The problem is that now I need to deploy files (that is, to copy a phisical copy of the file into a directory). My first solution is open file, load into memory and then write to another file, but I think that it would exists a faster method to deploy files.

Any ideas?

Comment: By PHYSFS, do you mean PhysicsFS (http://icculus.org/physfs/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes, going through each file, reading it and then writing it is what you want. Note that you probably shouldn't load the entire file into memory at once, though - instead use [PHYSFS_read](http://icculus.org/physfs/docs/html/physfs_8h.html#a91234f576477f7de67d635761d01aa7b) to read a fixed buffer (64kb or so should be good) from the source file, write it to the destination file, and repeat.

Comment: A fixed buffer of 64KB. Why? What is the deal?

Comment: @Killrazor, loading a multi-gigabyte file all into memory will cause a lot of swapping, which will slow you down. On the other hand, going one byte at a time is slow due to overhead. So 64kb is a nice medium, usually giving decent efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Faster solution would be creating a [hard link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) to an existing file (if you're not copying from a different system), but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

If you need to create an actual physical copy - I don't think you can work around actually copying, and the way you suggested is the most efficient.

Comment: PHYSFS is a virtual filesystem implemented in userspace; it's not possible to hard link to files within it from a real filesystem

Comment: @bdonian - that's exactly why I wrote that hard link is probably not what he is looking for.